# C++ template deduction is not working

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-argument-deduction

For the following code:

```
#include<functional>
template<typename T>
void f(std::function<void(T)> g) {
}

template<typename T>
void g(T x) {
}

int main() {
   f(&g<int>);
}
```

C++14 compiler produces the error:

```
 no matching function for call to 'f(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
     f(&g<int>);
```

I am curious why is template argument deduction not working here.
It seems that, given that the argument of g is of type int, we can deduce that the argument of f is of type `std::function<void(int)>`, and, therefore `T = int` in f. Why does this not happen? I am interested in the relevant section of the C++ standard which explains this. Does T occur in a non-deduced context here?

The following similar code compiles:

```
#include<vector>
template<typename T>
void f(std::vector<T> vec) { 
}


int main() {
    f(std::vector<int>{});
}
```

So it's not the angle brackets  which create a non-deduced context.

Comment: `f(std::function<void(int)>(g<int>));`
works

Comment: xis, thanks. Actually, f<int>(&g<int>); works as well. My problem is that I can't explain any of these behaviors according to what's written in the standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function expects an argument of type `std::function`, but you're passing it a pointer to function instead. `&g<int>` is *convertible* to the `std::function` parameter type, but template argument deduction requires exact matches (except for the adjustments allowed by [*[temp.deduct.call]/2,3,4*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call)), user defined conversions are not considered.

Writing `f(std::function<void(int)>(g<int>))` will work because you're now passing an `std::function`, so template argument deduction will succeed.

`f<int>(&g<int>)` also works because you've now explicitly specified `T`, it no longer participates in template argument deduction and user defined conversions will be attempted.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense! I do not think that argument deduction requires "exact" matches though. For instance, if I add "const" to the type of the f's argument in my second example, it will still compile. So, I guess there are some conversions which are allowed.

Comment: @Evgenii.Balai Yeah yeah, I simplified it a bit too much :) Fixed now.

Comment: @Evgenii.Balai: A top level `const` in an argument type is not part of the function signature, so the match is still exact in that case. A non-exact match that does work is a reference.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `&g<int>` is `void(*)(int)`. Therefore the compiler tries to generate a function with signature `void f<>(void(*)(int))` which it cannot do from your template. The type `std::function<void(int)>` is a completely different type.

In your similar code, the object `std::vector<int>{}`is of type `std::vector<int>`, therefore the compiler tries to generate a function `void f<>(std::vector<int>)` which it can do from the supplied template by deducing `T`to be `int`.

When specifying `f<int>`, the compiler has no need to deduce the type, and therefore cannot fail to do so. Moreover, while in deduced context no implicit conversions are considered, they *are* considered in non-deduced context. So by providing the type explicitly and thus making the function argument a non-deduced context, you allow the compiler to use implicit conversion to initialize the `std::function<void(int)>` argument with `g<int>`.