# Passing a C-style array to `span<T>`

Tags: c++, c++20

C++20 introduced `std::span`, which is a view-like object that can take in a continuous sequence, such as a C-style array, `std::array`, and `std::vector`. A common problem with a C-style array is it will decay to a pointer when passing to a function. Such a problem can be solved by using `std::span`:

```cpp
size_t size(std::span<int> s)
{
    return s.size();
}

int main()
{
    std::array arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
    auto il = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int c_arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << size(arr) << size(vec) << size(il) << size(c_arr);
}
```

This would print `5555`, as expected. However, `size` probably shouldn't take in only containers of `int`. Instead it should take in containers of any type. However, changing the `size` to a templated function, that takes in a `std::span<T>`, it can no longer substitute the C-style array successfully, while the others can:

```cpp
template<typename T>
size_t size(std::span<T> s)
{
    return s.size();
}

int main()
{
    std::array arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
    auto il = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int c_arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << size(arr) << size(vec) << size(il) << size(c_arr);
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
    // error: no matching function for call to 'size(int [5])'
    // note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    // note: mismatched types 'std::span<_Type, 18446744073709551615>' and 'int*'
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PaGq6xYjE)

Is this the correct behavior? If so, is there a way to accept a C-style array with `span<T>`?

Comment: If this is about having a free size function, then just use `std::size`. That wheel was already invented and rounded.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica No, it's not about `size`, I'm trying to test `span`.

Comment: Eh, you are not testing `std::span` as much as you are testing template argument deduction. That topic is already covered well enough with plenty of types that look like `TT<T>`. A span is not special.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The question is not why this fails for `int[]`, but why it works for all the other types! Unfortunately, you have fallen prey to [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) which is actually calling `std::size` instead of the `size` function you have written. This is because all overloads of your function fail, and so it looks in the namespace of the first argument for a matching function, where it finds `std::size`. Rerun your program with the function renamed to something else:

```
template<typename T>
size_t my_size(std::span<T> s)
{
    return s.size();
}
```

And on GCC 12 I get

```
prog.cc:18:25: error: no matching function for call to 'my_size(std::array<int, 5>&)'
   18 |     std::cout << my_size(arr) << my_size(vec) << my_size(il) << my_size(c_arr);
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~~~
prog.cc:7:8: note: candidate: 'template<class T> size_t my_size(std::span<_Type, 18446744073709551615>)'
    7 | size_t my_size(std::span<T> s)
      |        ^~~~~~~
prog.cc:7:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:18:25: note:   'std::array<int, 5>' is not derived from 'std::span<_Type, 18446744073709551615>'
   18 |     std::cout << my_size(arr) << my_size(vec) << my_size(il) << my_size(c_arr);
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

plus similar errors for all the other types. If your question is why is this failing; then the short answer is that template type deduction is far more strict than regular type deduction and so unless you give it an exact match (more or less), it will fail. For a more detailed explanation, read a similar question such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293256/c-template-deduction-is-not-working) which deals with something similar.

Comment: I liked the term "prey" :)

Answer (score 16):

Well, as [Dominic said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70117922/passing-a-c-style-array-to-spant/70118293#70118293), the function you wrote doesn't work with any of those types. You can try passing spans created from your containers like this:

```
std::cout << getSize(std::span(arr));
std::cout << getSize(std::span(vec.begin(), vec.end()));
std::cout << getSize(std::span(il.begin(), il.end()));
std::cout << getSize(std::span(c_arr));
```

Or you can also template your function for C-style arrays and standard containers:

```
// For std containers
template<class T>
size_t getSize(T myContainer)
{
    return std::span(myContainer.begin(), myContainer.end()).size();
}

// For c-style arrays
template<typename T, int n>
size_t getSize(T (&myArray)[n])
{
    return std::span<T>(myArray).size();
}
```